# C#: capture screen from Windows service

Tags: c#, image-capture

i have to capture screenshot of Desktop after every one second. in Winform application it is running fine. but after moving the code to Windows Service it is not capturing the screenshot. Any idea why it is not doing so?

here is the code

```
public partial class ScreenCaptureService : ServiceBase
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        public ScreenCaptureService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            this.timer.Interval = 1000;
            this.timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

        }

        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            CaptureScreen();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(this.ServiceName, Environment.MachineName))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    new EventSourceCreationData(
                        this.ServiceName,
                        Environment.MachineName
                        )
                );
            }

            EventLog.WriteEntry(this.ServiceName, "The OnStart event has been called");
            this.timer.Enabled = true;
            CaptureScreen();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(this.ServiceName, "The OnStop event has been called");
            this.timer.Enabled = false;
        }

        static int count = 1;
        private void CaptureScreen()
        {

            Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);

            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);

            printscreen.Save(@"C:\printscreen" + count++ + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            EventLog.WriteEntry(this.ServiceName, "Screenshot Captured");
        }
}
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002064/screen-capture-from-windows-service

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200341/capture-screen-on-server-desktop-session/12851218

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have "Allow service to interact with desktop" checked (in the service properties)?

Comment: on windows xp i know this is the solution but im not sure if it works with windows visa/7

Comment: thanks. this option was unchecked. how can i check it using code.

Comment: Petoj is correct. This will work on XP, but Vista/7 will not allow this.