# Postmessage function in QTP for simulating Printscreen key does not work

Tags: vba, qtp, postmessage

I am using the following code to simulate a PrintScreen button press to capture the image of a Internet Explorer window. I have assigned Printscreen as a Hotkey in Greenshot tool to capture the image of the full page in one go without having to scroll.

```
Extern.Declare micLong, "PostMessage", "user32.dll", "PostMessageA", micHwnd, micLong, micLong, micLong

Const WM_KEYDOWN = 273
Const VK_SNAPSHOT = 44

iResult = Extern.PostMessage( Hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_SNAPSHOT, 0)
```

But somehow the value of `iResult` is always 1. `Hwnd` is the actual window handle of the Internet explorer window which is passed to the `Postmessage` function. The reason why I am using this approach is because the screenshot capturing process needs to be automated completely and should run when the system is locked as well. `SendKeys` does not work when system is locked and so I had to move to `Post Message`.

Could someone please help me out with this.

Comment: Fyi, you'll probably get a black screen when trying to take screenshots on a locked desktop under normal circumstances, but I would be interested to know if Greenshot can get around that.

Comment: But somehow Greenshot does not seem to be picking up either the KeyDown or anything else. Is there something wrong with the code, am I missing something? :(

Comment: The problem is, this code does not work when the system is unlocked also..

Comment: I can provide a method that works on an unlocked desktop using keyb_event, but it also does not work on a locked desktop since Windows ignores most keyboard input in that situation (and so is no improvement over SendKeys).

Comment: Steelbird I have just answered your question at [LearnQTP forums](http://www.learnqtp.com/forums/Thread-Postmessage-function-in-QTP-for-simulating-Printscreen-key-does-not-work) Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the console is locked, the whole `WinStation` of the user session is not connected, thus the desktop does not behave in the same way as in unlocked state. It does not redraw, and more. I don´t think it is possible to ignore that. The screenshots will never show anything if the console is locked.

Ignoring that fact for a minute, I see you only send the `WM_KEYDOWN` message. If the user presses a key, Windows sends a `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_KEYUP` message for that, reflecting the depressing and releasing of the key. It might be that the target application polls for the `WM_KEYUP` message to trigger the screenshot. Also, it is very common for applications to ignore the `WM_KEYDOWN` message and react to `WM_KEYUP` only, among others because only on `WM_KEYUP`, you can query the Shift state of the keyboard, making it possible to differentiate between "A" and "Shift-A", for example.

In [Capture screen on server desktop session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200341/capture-screen-on-server-desktop-session), somebody solved a similar issue.