# Screen shot of windows desktop on Login Screen

Tags: authentication, screen, screenshot

Is it possible to take a screen shot of windows desktop on Login Screen ?

I build a windows service in C# that captures the screen but when logged off a I got the
exception with message "The handle is invalid."

I used this code

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SelectionRectangle.Width, SelectionRectangle.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
   g.CopyFromScreen(SourcePoint, DestinationPoint, SelectionRectangle.Size);
}
```

Does using Windows API can solve the problem ?

I am trying to achieve something like Ultra VNC can do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you're on the wrong WindowStation. Have a look at these articles;

[Why does print screen in a Windows Service return a black image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712532/why-does-print-screen-in-a-windows-service-return-a-black-image)

[Screen capture from windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002064/screen-capture-from-windows-service)

You may need to enumerate the win-stations and locate the login desktop and use that.